# How to find the transition function for two overlapping charts of $\mathbb{R}P^2$?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, projective-space

The real 2-dim projective space $\mathbb{R}P^2$ can be covered by the following 3 sets of unoriented lines through the origin un $\mathbb{R}^3$:

$ U_x \doteq $ { all lines not lying in the yz plane}

$ U_y \doteq $ { all lines not lying in the xz plane}

$ U_y \doteq $ { all lines not lying in the xy plane}

The lines $L$ belonging to these patches can be parameterized as

$L \in U_x: (u_1 = \frac{y}{x}, u_2 = z/x)$

$L \in U_y: (u_1 = \frac{x}{y}, u_2 = z/y)$

$L \in U_z: (u_1 = \frac{x}{z}, u_2 = y/z)$

How can I fand the transitions between two of these charts, in order to for example investigate differentiability of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ as a 2-dim manifold?
Or would I need to investigate the transition function for two coordinate descriptions of a singly line, that differ only by a scaling factor, for that purpose?

Comment: To supplement Lee Mosher's excellent, comprehensive answer, the short of it is to perform elementary algebra, setting aside that some homogeneous coordinates can be zero. For instance, if $(u_{1}, u_{2}) = (\frac{y}{x}, \frac{z}{x})$ are affine coordinates in $U_{x}$ and $(v_{1}, v_{2}) = (\frac{x}{y}, \frac{z}{y})$ are coordinates in $U_{y}$, then $v_{1} = \frac{1}{u_{1}}$ and $v_{2} = \frac{u_{2}}{u_{1}}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to answer this question, to start with it helps to write the parameterizations of $U_x$, $U_y$, $U_z$ as functions, where $U_x$, $U_y$, $U_z$ are the ranges of the functions, and the domains are open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (in this case, all of $\mathbb{R}^2$).

So for example your parameterization of the set $U_z$ is in the form

$$L \in U_z: (u_1 = \frac{x}{z}, \,\, u_2 = \frac{y}{z})
$$

I can see in this formula that you are parameterizing $U_z$ using all of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $(u_1,u_2)$ coordinates, but it helps to express this parameterization as an actual function $L_z : \mathbb{R}^2 \to U_z$, as follows:
$$L_z(u_1,u_2) = \{(x,y,z) \,\bigm|\, \exists s \in \mathbb{R} \, \text{such that} \, x = u_1 s, \,\, y = u_2 s, \,\, z = s\}
$$
where I'm using $s$ as a "parameter along the line".

Similarly for $L_y : \mathbb{R}^2 \to U_y$, except I'm going to use $(v_1,v_2)$ as coordinates for $U_y$ in order to avoid confusion, and I'll use $t$ as the parameter along the line:
$$L_y(v_1,v_2) = \{(x,y,z) \,\bigm|\, \exists t \in \mathbb{R} \, \text{such that} \, x = v_1 t, \,\, y= t, \,\, z=v_2 t\}
$$
Now let's compute a formula for the overlap map 
$$L_y^{-1} \circ L_z : L_z^{-1}(U_y \cap U_z) \to L_y^{-1}(U_y \cap U_z)
$$
The goal is to rewrite the equation 
$$(v_1,v_2) = L_y^{-1} \circ L_z(u_1,u_2)
$$
as two equations of the form 
$$v_1 = f(u_1,u_2), \,\, v_2 = g(u_1,u_2)
$$
and to get explicit formulas for $f$ and $g$.

To do this take any line $L \in U_y \cap U_z$. There is a unique $(u_1,u_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $L = L_z(u_1,u_2)$ as defined above. Similarly, there is a unique $(v_1,v_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $L=L_y(v_1,v_2)$. Thus we have $L_z(u_1,u_2) = L = L_y(v_1,v_2)$. Using the formulas above we get
$$\{(x,y,z) \,\bigm|\, \exists s \in \mathbb{R} \, \text{such that} \, x = u_1 s, \,\, y= u_2 s, \,\, z = s\}$$
$$ =
\{(x,y,z) \,\bigm|\, \exists t \in \mathbb{R} \, \text{such that} \, x = v_1 t, \,\, y= t, \,\, z=v_2t\}
$$
We must eliminate $x,y,z,s,t$. Setting $x$ coordinates equal, and similarly $y$ coordinates and $z$ coordinates we get
$$u_1 s = v_1 t, \,\, u_2 s = t, \,\,  s = v_2 t
$$
Using $s=v_2 t$ to eliminate $t$ we get
$$u_1 v_2 t = v_1 t, \,\, u_2 v_2 t = t
$$
Plugging in $t=1$ we get
$$u_1 v_2 = v_1, \,\, u_2 v_2 = 1
$$
Solving we get
$$v_1 = \frac{u_1}{u_2}, \,\, v_2 = \frac{1}{u_2}
$$

Comment: Nice explanations, I like this!